# Breaking string into array string with conditions

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a string which is like this `13/03/14 17:18:03 0035880 FINLAND 00:00:23 3 2.34`.Now i will briefly describe how this string can also be..It can be like

```
13/03/14 17:18:03 0035880 FINLAND DEN 00:00:23 3 2.34

13/03/14 17:18:03 0035880 FINLAND DEN MEN 00:00:23 3 2.34

13/03/14 17:18:03 0035880 FINLAND DEN MEN CHEN 00:00:23 3 2.34
```

Now in my program I have to break these strings into array string based on spaces.The sequence of the string will be same except the place at `FINLAND`,`FINLAND DEN` etc .Now as per my requirement I have to add `FINLAND DEN MEN CHEN` into one array element.

I am not getting how to add these four different sub-strings `FINLAND DEN MEN CHEN` into one array element if it comes in the string.

Here is my c# code..

```
string currentLine;
string[] arrline = currentLine.Split(' ');
```

Please help me to solve my this issue.

Comment: Are these lines in a file?

Comment: @TimSchmelter No these lines are a string and i am reading it one by one

Comment: Since the data is neither delimited or fixed width, what happens if the variable length text data includes a time?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I want to split the given string i.e `13/03/14 17:18:03 0035880 FINLAND DEN MEN CHEN 00:00:23 3 2.34` into string array based on spaces with FINLAND DEN MEN CHEN as one array element like `arr[0]=13/03/14 , arr[1]=17:18:03 , arr[2]=0035880 , arr[3]=FINLAND DEN MEN CHEN` and like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be

```
var wordsArray = arrLine.Where(str => str.All(Char.IsLetter)).ToList();
```

It searches for entries where all the characters are letters

---

Based on your comments you are after the following

```
    var arrline = current.Split(' ')
                         .GroupBy(x => x.All(Char.IsLetter) ? "True" : x)
                         .Select(g => string.Join(" ", g))
                         .ToList();
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Ok and how to add whole string into string array with `words` as one array element

Comment: @ShivamShlom - If you mean you wish to join this back up into one string it would be `string.Join(" ", wordsArray);`

Comment: I want to split the given string i.e `13/03/14 17:18:03 0035880 FINLAND DEN MEN CHEN 00:00:23 3 2.34` into string array based on spaces with `FINLAND DEN MEN CHEN` as one array element like `arr[0]=13/03/14 , arr[1]=17:18:03 , arr[2]=0035880 , arr[3]=FINLAND DEN MEN CHEN` and like this..

Comment: How to do it like i mentioned in my above comment?

Comment: @ShivamShlom - No worries, I just edited in a small optimization to stop having to calculate if all the characters are letters twice

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `DateTime.TryParseExact`, string-methods like `Substring` or `Remove` and LINQ methods like `TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit)`.

For example wth this query:

```
 string lines = @"13/03/14 17:18:03 0035880 FINLAND DEN 00:00:23 3 2.34
                  13/03/14 17:18:03 0035880 FINLAND DEN MEN 00:00:23 3 2.34
                  13/03/14 17:18:03 0035880 FINLAND DEN MEN CHEN 00:00:23 3 2.34";

var lineInfos = lines.Split(new[]{Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(l => l.Trim().Length > 33)
    .Select(l => {
        string line = l.Trim();
        string Number = null;
        string Country = null;
        string Timespan = null;
        DateTime? dtNullable = null;
        DateTime dt;
        String datePart = line.Remove(17);
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(datePart, "dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
        {
            dtNullable = dt;
            // extract the number from the following digits after the date:
            Number = string.Join("", line.Substring(18).TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit));
            // take the timspan at the end with a fixed length of 15 characters
            int tsLength = line.Length - 15;
            Timespan = line.Substring( tsLength ); // take from end
            // take the country from the rest 
            Country = line.Substring(18 + Number.Length, line.Length - 15 - 18 - Number.Length);                      
            return new { Date = dtNullable, Number, Country, Timespan };
        }
        else
            return new { Date = dtNullable, Number, Country, Timespan };
    })
    .Where(x => x.Date.HasValue); // take only valid lines

foreach (var lInfo in lineInfos)
    Console.WriteLine(lInfo.ToString());
```

Result:

```
{ Date = 13.03.2014 17:18:03, Number = 0035880, Country =  FINLAND DEN , Timespan = 00:00:23 3 2.34 }
{ Date = 13.03.2014 17:18:03, Number = 0035880, Country =  FINLAND DEN MEN , Timespan = 00:00:23 3 2.34 }
{ Date = 13.03.2014 17:18:03, Number = 0035880, Country =  FINLAND DEN MEN CHEN , Timespan = 00:00:23 3 2.34 }
```

as `List<String[]>`:

```
List<String[]> result = lineInfos 
    .Select(x => new[]{ x.Date.ToString(), x.Number, x.Country, x.Timespan })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Split(currentLine, "(?<![a-zA-Z]) | (?![a-zA-Z])");
```

The delimiter is a space symbol not preceeded by any letter or not followed by any letter.
So, space between two letters doesn't match, between letter and digit matches.